# Check Aria Status of HTML Website via VBA

Tags: html, vba

I am working on a VBA algorithm in order to automate an interaction with a website. The automation works quite well, except one little problem, which has been causing me quite a lot of headaches (also I am relatively new to this web-automation programming). It is an internal website, so I cannot post a link, but I'll try to make it as transparent as I can.

**Here is what I do:**

I am inputting a name on a website into an element via `GetElementByID("ID").value = "Name"`. Then the website needs time to process that information and does not allow me to enter information into another element until this part is completed. While the website is processing the information a popup basically freezes the website.

**Here is my Problem:**

The time it takes the website to process the information can vary from 2 seconds to 2 minutes. So I am trying to figure out a way how I can get going with my program in the shortest timeframe, after the processing is complete.

**What I have tried:**

1) `application.wait` ; rather obvious, but the very least elegant way and not very reliable, because the processing time varies considerably.

2) `IE.ReadyState = 4` or `IE.busy`; does not work, because the website it fully loaded whilst this processing takes place.

3) I built a function which basically loops, whilst the innerhtml of the element is not the name. I thought this would be a cool solution, but the issue is that the innerhtml change is sometimes already completed, whilst the popup is still there. (The function works in other parts of the code).

4) I built a function that loops until it cannot find the popup via `GetElementByID("waitingPopUp")`. Did not work, because the element is technically always there.

**What I think should work:**

So this popup this the main problem. The only thing is that whilst the popup is visible the status is on `aria-hidden="false"`, otherwise `aria-hidden="true"`. Hence my question is if there is a way I can access this aria status via VBA? Ideally I'd like to build a function a long the lines of "loop while element("popup") is on `aria-hidden="false"`". Is that possible?

Regards

Comment: You mention VBA, what type of backend are you using? Web Forms? ASP MVC?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, as I am quite new to it. I'm using Excel 2010 and IE 11.